# how to use jquery to drag and drop from multiple tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

im building a toolbox application that has panes of items that can be dropped onto a canvas. problem is.. when i build the application i want multiple tabs of items that can be dropped on to a canvas(div) and the co-ordinates recorded

I have seen some good examples of how to use jquery to do drag and drop and separately on how to do tabs. but nothing that combines the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

[jquery-ui connect lists through tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs)

However it's a tutorial for jquery-ui's "sortable" feature, so perhaps more than what your looking for. But it's tutorial could still be useful, as it's using dropable as well.

Comment: got me half way there.. some playing has got me over the hill, cheers

Comment: @Chris Mccabe glad to be of assistance :-) Quite funny just last week I was working on almost exactly the same problem.